# Django: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'qs' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

This is my view:

```
  @login_required
  def ledger1_detail_view(request, pk1, pk2):
       company_details = get_object_or_404(company, pk=pk1)
       ledger1_details = get_object_or_404(ledger1, pk=pk2)

       form_class = DateRangeForm

        if request.method == 'POST':
             form = form_class(request.POST or None)
             if form.is_valid():
                 start_date = request.POST.get('start_date')
                  end_date   = request.POST.get('end_date')
                  qs    : journal.objects.filter(Q(User=request.user) | Q(Date__range=(form.cleaned_data['start_date'], form.cleaned_data['end_date'])))

                  return HttpResponseRedirect(ledger1_details.get_absolute_url())
       else:
            form = DateRangeForm()


      context = {

          'company_details' : company_details,
          'ledger1_details' : ledger1_details,
          'journal_list'    : qs,

      }

      return render(request, 'accounting_double_entry/ledger1_details.html', context)
```

This is my DaterangeForm:

```
  class DateRangeForm(forms.Form):
       start_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
       end_date   = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
```

This is my journal model:

```
  class journal(models.Model):
      Date = models.DateField()
      By = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Debitledgers')
      To = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Creditledgers')
      Debit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
      Credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
```

I want to filter the journal objects in ledger1_detail_view for a specific daterange...So,I have created a form named 'Daterangeform" which can filter the journal objects where "Date" of the journal objects is between the "start_date" and "end_date" of Daterangeform which will be given by the user according to their choise...

I have done some form validation in my "ledger1_detail_view" as you can see...But getting this error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'qs' referenced before assignment"

Can anyone help me to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: It is `qs = ...`, not `qs: ...`.

Comment: Furthermore you need to specify a `qs` in case the method is not POST, or the form is not valid: right now there are two codepaths where `qs` is not set.

Comment: Can you tell me how that can be done?

Comment: The error is showing in this line of code:   " 'journal_list'    : qs, "

Comment: what is not clear about the error message, and the explanation?

Comment: I have set qs when the form is not valid,But the error message is still coming....I have done "qs = journal.objects.filter(User=request.user)" if the form is not vlalid

Comment: what happens when request.method is GET or anything but POST

Comment: @NiladryKar: indeed, that is the second comment, only in case it is a POST request, and the form is valid, `qs` will be set (and you do not even do anything with this). But now you use `qs` as well in case of a GET request, or in case of a POST request and invalid form.

Comment: Means I have to specify something to qs if request.method is not equal to "POST"??

Comment: Or in case the form is *invalid*. It is also very strange that you redirect in case the form is valid here, and the fact that you use a POST in the first place. Search results are typically done through GET.

Comment: Can you tell me what changes do I have to make if I change the "POST" to "GET"??

Comment: @NiladryKar: nooo.... I really suggest to redesign and reimplement this. The above view contains more errors than lines of code. For example `request.POST or None` can go wrong in some cases if all fields are non-required, but the form is thus valid with an empty post. This is back the *XY* problem. Instead of thinking *how* you need to implement/fix this. First come up with a *clean* specification *what* you are going to implement. It is rather strange here to use a POST in the first place. So I advice to go back to the drawing table.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because if you don't have `request.method == 'POST'` then there is no definition of `qs` in context dictionary.

Define your context above all the conditions and inside the conditions add items in context dictionary like this -

```
@login_required
  def ledger1_detail_view(request, pk1, pk2):
       company_details = get_object_or_404(company, pk=pk1)
       ledger1_details = get_object_or_404(ledger1, pk=pk2)
       context = {
          'company_details' : company_details,
          'ledger1_details' : ledger1_details,
      }
       form_class = DateRangeForm

        if request.method == 'POST':
             form = form_class(request.POST or None)
             if form.is_valid():
                 start_date = request.POST.get('start_date')
                  end_date   = request.POST.get('end_date')
                  qs  = journal.objects.filter(Q(User=request.user) | Q(Date__range=(form.cleaned_data['start_date'], form.cleaned_data['end_date'])))
                  context['journal_list'] = qs
                  return HttpResponseRedirect(ledger1_details.get_absolute_url())
        else:
             form = DateRangeForm()



      return render(request, 'accounting_double_entry/ledger1_details.html', context)
```

This is the most convenient way to avoid `UnboundLocalError`.